# WSO2 Agent "Cannot proceed the authentication" but website works fine

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I've gotten WSO2 working on the server. I can login through the management console and EMM, publisher, and store are all working. I can create a new user through the EMM dashboard, and the email is sent correctly. So everything is fine while using the website.

I'm using the sample APK that comes with WSO2 to do some development, but every time I try to register the app pops up "Authentication Failed - Cannot proceed the authentication. Please contact an administrator." And there is no output in the console when this happens.

If I put in the incorrect credentials I get a separate error, "Authentication Failed - Incorrect login information. Please try again." So I know my credentials are correct.

What does this mean? Is there another place to find more detailed logs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging the Android-agent ? If so you might be able to provide more information regarding this issue by looking at agent debug logs.

BTW did you tried enrolling as the admin user?